# Decimating rows in spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Is there such an option to preserve only every 10th row in my spreadsheet? It can be Excel or Calc. Quality standards want some noise to be added.

Comment: Set up a helper column and fill the first 9 cells with a `no` and the 10th with a `yes`.  
Select the range of these 10 cells and use *Autofill Down* to repeat the values over all rows. 

At last use an AutoFilter to filter for all lines with a `no` and delet them. (Not worth an answer)

Comment: Can you make this the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placed in cell A1, the formula

`=MOD(ROW(A1),10)`

will repeat with values 0-9 when you fill it down. You can then use filtering to delete the rows that you don't want. Note that the result of the formula will then change if you delete (rather than clear) the rows. (Although filtering doesn't update until you ask it to.)

Alternatively,

`=MOD(ROW(A1),10)=0`

will only return `TRUE` every tenth row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Sampling function in the Analysis Toolpak, which you will have to install. Unfortunately, MS makes you work to find it if you are using anything later than Office/Excel 2003.

1. Go to *File* menu and click on *Options*. On *Excel Options* window, click on *Add-Ins*. At the bottom, select *Manage:* Excel Add-ins and click *Go*.
2. Check the *Analysis Tookpack* and click *OK*. Now select the Data menu to see the associated ribbon. Over on the right, select *Data Analysis*.
3. Scroll down to *Sampling* and click *OK*. You will see a window that allows you to specify the sampling period, cell ranges, etc. To sample every 10th cell, select *Periodic* and *10* for the period.

In Excel 2003, the above is accomplished in only a couple clicks, indicating how grossly inefficient the ribbon is.

Answer (score 0):

Use the analysis toolkits sampling function. It asks you for the input data range, the period you wish to decimate by and the an output cell or range (it does not really care it will fill whatever cells it needs starting at the first one you select)

Comment: It would improve your answer if you explained how to install this addin